# Invalid security protocol `PLAINTEXT "` defined in listener.security.protocol.map

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

Helllo All,

My docker-compose.yml changes is below :-

```
kafka-docker:
    image: onfluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka-docker
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISE_HOST_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS= "INTERNAL1://kafka-docker:9090,EXTERNAL1://localhost:9092"
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS= INTERNAL1://kafka-docker:9092,EXTERNAL1://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP= "INTERNAL1:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL1:PLAINTEXT"
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME= INTERNAL1
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=test:1:1
```

Im Getting the Error `org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid security protocol PLAINTEXT defined in listener.security.protocol.map`
while docker-compose up -d